# Mi app de node abre en el localhost pero no en Heroku

Tags: nodejs, socket, heroku, socket.io, websocket

Programé una app en node.js que funcionaba en heroku, pero cuando le agregué socket.io, a pesar de que en el localhost andaba, al subirlo a heroku no funciona y me dice Aplication error. Cuando pruebo heroku logs --tail me dice:

heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=semaweek.herokuapp.com request_id=4b26865a-d900-443a-9b07-7660121ccdbe fwd="190.244.71.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-25T01:00:08.664599+00:00

heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=semaweek.herokuapp.com request_id=acfb9674-33b9-49d5-9006-3a766c0a6411 fwd="190.244.71.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Semaweek es el nombre de la aplicación.

El problema puede ser la conexión entre socket.io y el servidor de heroku? intenté escribiendo dentro del paréntesis de io() la dirección https del servidor que me da heroku pero sigue sin funcionar

Qué debería colocar acá?

```
                      ↓
    const socket = io( );
```

Agradecería mucho sus respuestas